# Why is the jQuery cookie plugin not saving a float variable as a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm not exactly sure if it has to do with the float variable, but I do this:

```
if ($.cookie('latitude') == undefined && $.cookie('longitude') == undefined) {
    if (window.location.search.indexOf('latitude') <= -1 || (window.location.search.indexOf('longitude') <= -1)) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                window.location.replace(window.location.pathname + '?latitude=' + latitude + '&longitude=' + longitude);
            }, function (position) {
                window.location.replace(window.location.pathname + '?latitude=error&longitude=error');
            }, timeout = 7000);
            $.cookie('latitude', latitude, {expires: 7, path: '/'});
            $.cookie('longitude', longitude, {expires: 7, path: '/'});
        }
    }
}
```

But the cookies created in the last two lines stay undefined. I have been working a lot so I may be missing something silly.

Comment: I saw that, tried latitude.toString() and it was still undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a common mistake with *[promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)*. You have to set your cookies inside the `getCurrentPosition` callback, where are defined the variables `latitude` and `longitude`. Out of there, those vars will be always undefined, since they will be out of their scope:

```
if ($.cookie('latitude') == undefined && $.cookie('longitude') == undefined) {
    if (window.location.search.indexOf('latitude') <= -1 || (window.location.search.indexOf('longitude') <= -1)) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                window.location.replace(window.location.pathname + '?latitude=' + latitude + '&longitude=' + longitude);

                $.cookie('latitude', latitude, {expires: 7, path: '/'});
                $.cookie('longitude', longitude, {expires: 7, path: '/'});
            }, function (position) {
                window.location.replace(window.location.pathname + '?latitude=error&longitude=error');
            }, timeout = 7000);
        }
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes a lot of sense. I just moved those lines there from elsewhere and completely looked over the failure function.